# How to launch web AR on android from a QR code

Tags: android, android-intent, android-augmented-reality, web-ar

Given a GLTF (or GLB) asset, one can launch the WebAR experience on an android phone via a url like:
`intent://arvr.google.com/scene-viewer/1.0?file=<insertURLHere>&title=MyWebArAsset&disable_occlusion=true&mode=ar_preferred#Intent;scheme=https;package=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox;action=android.intent.action.VIEW;end;`
(https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/scene-viewer)
However, if you put that same intent URL into a QR code and scan it, instead of opening in the Web AR viewer, it takes me to a google search.
If i remove the intent, and just put the file-path into the QR code, it just downloads the file.
Is there any way to trigger web AR viewer on android directly from a QR code?

Comment: You should identify which bar code reader you are using. Do realize that QR code readers may not properly parse the URI in Intent format. Check the logcat to see if that is the case. One thing to try as a possible workaround may be to include the WebAR URI as a redirect from a site or link shortener so that Chrome is handling Intent construction.

Comment: Seems to be that the only way to go is the workaround you mentioned; include the WebAR URI as a redirect from a site or link shortener so that Chrome is handling Intent construction. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QR Code readers may not interpret the WebAR URI correctly due to the 'Intent' format.

One workaround is to include the WebAR URI as a redirect from a site or a link shortener so that Chrome is handling the intent construction.

The additional 'wrapping of the WebAR URI' may allow for alternate behaviors for non-Android devices or truthful non-supporting browsers via User Agent checking.